# Spring profiles with Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm running a spring boot project with three different property files (application.properties, application-prod.properties, application-uat.properties. I'm using Maven and if I don't specify any argument, it will pick the default property file which is application.properties. Here's how the related files look.

application.properties

```
#Set active profile
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
    
#MongoDB configuration
spring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGODB_HOST:localhost}
spring.data.mongodb.port=${MONGODB_PORT:27017}
spring.data.mongodb.database=database
spring.data.mongodb.username=username
spring.data.mongodb.password=password
```

pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>UAT</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>uat</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>PROD</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

How can I achieve the same with Gradle? How can I let Gradle to pick the default (application.properties) if I don't specify any arguement?

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will be useful for you...

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html#migmvn:profiles_and_properties

Sample:

```
if (!hasProperty('buildProfile')) ext.buildProfile = 'default'  

apply from: "profile-${buildProfile}.gradle"  

task greeting {
    doLast {
        println message  
    }
}
```

---

```sh
#profile-default.gradle
ext.message = 'foobar' 
 
#profile-test.gradle
ext.message = 'testing 1 2 3'  

#profile-prod.gradle
ext.message = 'Hello, world!'
```

This link can be useful too:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: How does it pick different property files when you pass different arguments and how does it pick the default property file which is application.properties if you don't specify any arguments?

Comment: First question: `apply from: "profile-${buildProfile}.gradle"`

Second question: `if (!hasProperty('buildProfile')) ext.buildProfile = 'default'`

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 7.1

this how i managed to set the spring.profiles.active in the command line

./gradlew someTask -Dparameterexample -DparameterExample2 -Dspring.profiles.active=yourprofile

```
task someTask(type:JavaExec){
   javaexec{
    environment 
     'spring.profiles.active',System.getProperty('spring.profiles.active')
      systemProperties = [ parameterexample : System.getProperty('parameterexample') 
      
             ]
     } 
}
```